# PDFNet 5.7 .Net 4.5 Windows 8.1x64 crash

Tags: pdftron, pdfnet

I've encountered a crash when using PDFNet 5.7 in a .Net 4.5 64 bit application running on Windows 8.1 The issue is only occurring in this scenario. .Net 3.5 works fine with Windows 8.1 and .Net 4.5 works fine on Windows 8.1 64-bit when run in 32 bit application.

The actual crash is (from EventLog):

Faulting application name: PdfNetDriver.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x543f4825
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17055, time stamp: 0x532954fb
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005bf8
Faulting process id: 0x1174
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfe98da8d3f94c
Faulting application path: 
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: e6be82fb-5580-11e4-8263-b8ca3a956626
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

FileLoadException

Faulting application name: PdfNetDriver.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x543f4825
Faulting module name: PDFNet.dll, version: 5.7.0.0, time stamp: 0x4f061bd8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000007682d3
Faulting process id: 0x1174
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfe98da8d3f94c
Faulting application path: 
Faulting module path: \bin\x64\Debug\PDFNet.dll
Report Id: e6a6ab32-5580-11e4-8263-b8ca3a956626
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

When the exception occurs - the exe dies straight away. No exceptions pop up. Nothing can be done. The program never makes it through the method that initializes the PDFNet component, eg.:

```
public static void SubMain()
{
    // Initialize PDF
    PDFNet.Initialize(LIC_KEY);
    PDFNet.Terminate();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

PDFNet for .Net comes in four flavours, and each has a dependency on VC++ Redistributable

- .Net 2.0 x86 : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29
- .Net 2.0 x64 : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336
- .Net 4.0 x86 : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555
- .Net 4.0 x64 : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

So you say

> PDFNet 5.7 in a .Net 4.5 64 bit application running on Windows 8.1

does not work

I don't think the PDFNet .Net 2.0 build will work in .Net 4.5, so make sure you are using .Net 4.0 version. Since it is 64 bit you can use either the 32 or 64 bit versions. You just need to ensure the VC++ redistributable is available.

You can check what a particular PDFNEt.dll is by checking the details tab, in the properties menu, in Windows Explorer.
Make sure to expand the filename column as if it is 64bit that will be indicated at the end of the line.

[.Net 4.0 PDFNet Getting Started Guide](https://api.pdftron.com/v2/view/ODdhZjFkYjAtYmQ0Yy00ODg5LWIyYjktZjI0NmI1NGVhYjdh)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a .Net 4.0 PDFNet version 5.7 available? I looked on your website and could only find a later version available. We are hoping to upgrade within the near future, but are currently unable to upgrade - which means that our builds cannot be run in that environment

Comment: No, old versions are not available. I would contact sales or support, about your options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We will be in contact shortly.